# Cannot use some methods in F# from C# class

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am having hard time figuring out why I cannot see/use some methods from C# type in F# function.

[image]

```
public class KafkaBus : IKafkaBus
{
    // this works and can be used
    public IObservable<Shared.Model.Message<T>> CreateConsumer<T>(string topic, Func<byte[], T> deserialize = null)

    // those cannot be found
    public Task<Confluent.Kafka.CommittedOffsets> CommitAsync<T>(Message<T> message)
    public Task<Confluent.Kafka.CommittedOffsets> CommitAsync(string topic, int partition, long offSet)
}
```

If I check object browser in F# solution under references, I see those methods listed:
[image]

I am using VS 2017 15.3, .NET Framework 4.6.1, library is referenced via nuget.

Comment: Your code sample shows a `Bus` class but your last screenshot is for the `KafkaBus` class. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Sorry for making this even harder. It was a mistake. Now class naming aligned.

Comment: If you type the `CommitAsync` code in, ignoring the fact that it doesn't appear in intellisense, and then build, does it compile? If not, what's the error?

Comment: You should also look out for the fact that intellisense won't update between C#/F# projects until you build them.

Comment: Yes, rebuilding is like ceremony already :)

Here is the error: 
Error FS0039 The field, constructor or member 'CommitAsync' is not defined. Gateway Service.fs 31 Active

Comment: Do you see the methods if you cast to the interface, ```(kafkaBus :> IKafkaBus).```

Comment: Tried that with no luck :/

Comment: Grasping at straws here: What type is `kafkaBus` in your F# code?  If it's an `IKafkaBus` and `CommitAsync` is only defined in the `KafkaBus` class, that could explain the missing members...

Comment: Hello Wilson, nice shot but unfortunately it is KafkaBus. Anyway, IKafkaBus expose same contract so it should not be different either using one or another.

Comment: Made sure that all reference paths are exactly as you expect?  I've often been building Debug mode and referencing a Release path...

Comment: Cannot really reproduce the problem in VS2015/.net 4.6.1. Could you be a bit more specific: which version of VS? Which .net version are your projects targeting? How do you reference which libraries (nuget / vs referncing projects vs referencing DLL-s directly)? Does your F# project reference Confluent.Kafka as well?

Comment: Hi, updated, it does reference Confluent.Kafka as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end **reopening project**, **rebuilding or simply restarting a machine** helps the cause... Seems like a bug in Visual Studio. Got help on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4ce168b-9765-42fb-8e85-65c7b05de08e/i-cannot-use-some-of-methods-from-c-class-in-f-program?forum=fsharpgeneral)